# editing value in sql server 2005 using vb6 causing the program to hang

Tags: sql-server-2005, vb6

I searched about editing value on the net and I did find it, but when I executed it, it returns no error and indeed it inputs the data into sql server but vb6 hangs and needs to be terminated.
It's a hotel system where I updated room status to 'Occupied'.

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
Me.AdodcRoomStatus.Refresh
With Me.AdodcRoomStatus

    .Recordset.MoveFirst
    Do Until .Recordset.EOF
    On Error Resume Next
    If (.Recordset.Fields![RoomNo] = Me.cRoomNo) Then
        .Recordset.Fields![RoomStatus].Value = "Occupied"
        '.Recordset.Fields("RoomStatus").Value = Me.cOccupied
        .Recordset.Update
    Else
    .Recordset.MoveNext
    End If
    Loop
    MsgBox "Changing Room Status Success", vbInformation
End With
End Sub
```

Coding where i add checkin here, if it can help

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
Me.AdodcCheckIn.Refresh
With Me.AdodcCheckIn.Recordset

.AddNew
.Fields![Cust_IC] = Me.cIdenfitication
.Fields![Check_In_Date] = Me.cDateArrive
.Fields![RoomNo] = Me.cRoomNo
.Update
Me.AdodcCheckIn.Refresh
MsgBox "Guests Are Checked In", vbInformation
End With
End Sub
```

Result is : Guests are checked in,data inputted. And then it goes to update room Status. It hangs there but the value is changed to 'Occupied' in Sql server.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a logical error. In the cmdUpdate_Click function, when the record is updated , there's no movenext OR exit loop. Use either of the 2 and it should stop going into hang state!

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
Me.AdodcRoomStatus.Refresh
With Me.AdodcRoomStatus

    .Recordset.MoveFirst
    Do Until .Recordset.EOF
    On Error Resume Next
    If (.Recordset.Fields![RoomNo] = Me.cRoomNo) Then
        .Recordset.Fields![RoomStatus].Value = "Occupied"
        '.Recordset.Fields("RoomStatus").Value = Me.cOccupied
        .Recordset.Update
    .Recordset.MoveNext
    Else
    .Recordset.MoveNext
    End If
    Loop
    MsgBox "Changing Room Status Success", vbInformation
End With
End Sub
```